# Crear una tabla (sqlite3) usando contenido de un Entry como nombre

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3

Estoy creando un programa en el cual se cree una tabla (con sqlite3) usando lo que ingresas en el `Entry` (nombre de la tabla), pero no puedo encontrar como sería el código ya que todo los ejemplos que he encontrado siempre utilizan una tabla definida, he pasado 2 días buscando en google ejemplos y no puedo encontrarlos.

Parte relevante de mi código:

```
mi_caso= StringVar()
Introducir_Nombre = Entry(Ventana_Central, textvariable=mi_caso,\ 
width=30, font=Fuente, ).place(Ventana_Central, x=350, y=40)

def  conexion_nombre_de_caso():
        try:
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("DB_Casos.db")
        micursor = conexion.cursor()
#Aquí es mi duda como escribir el código con la variable del Entry
        micursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + 
        Introducir_Nombre.get()\
        + "(ID VARCHAR(30), NUMERO INT, DESACTIVACION VARCHAR(30)")
        conexion.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Base_Datos", "Caso" + Introducir_Nombre.get()\
        + "Creado con éxito")

        conexion.close()
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("Atención!", "El Caso ya ha sido creado")


Boton_Aceptar = Button(width=8, height=1, text="Aceptar", bg="cornflower 
blue", command=conexion_nombre_de_caso)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En estos casos siempre elimina el `try-except` para que te deje ver las excepciones. Tienes varios problemas:

- Cuando instancias tu `tkinter.Entry` haces:

  ```
  Introducir_Nombre = Entry(Ventana_Central, textvariable=mi_caso,
                            width=30, font=Fuente,).place(Ventana_Central, x=350, y=40)
  ```

  Esto hace que el identificador `Introducir_Nombre` sea el retorno del método place, que es `None`. Esto causa que al hacer `Introducir_Nombre.get()` obtengas la siguiente excepción:

  > AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

  Si quieres asociar el widget a una variable, aplica `place`, `pack` o `grid` en otra línea:

  ```
  Introducir_Nombre = Entry(Ventana_Central, textvariable=mi_caso,
                            width=30, font=Fuente)
  Introducir_Nombre.place(Ventana_Central, x=350, y=40)
  ```
- A `place` no se le pasa el widget padre como argumento, en vez de:

  ```
  .place(Ventana_Central, x=350, y=40)
  ```

  debes hacer:

  ```
  .place(x=350, y=40)
  ```
- Dado que asocias una `StringVar` al `Entry`, usalo para obtener su contenido. En vez de:

  ```
  Introducir_Nombre.get()
  ```

  puedes hacer:

  ```
  mi_caso.get()
  ```
- Te falta cerrar un paréntesis en la cadena de la query:

  ```
   "(ID VARCHAR(30), NUMERO INT, DESACTIVACION VARCHAR(30))"
                                                          ^
                                                          ^
                                                          ^
  ```
- Al usar el parámetro `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, la tabla se crea si no existe, si existe no se hace nada y no se lanza ninguna excepción. Por lo tanto, tu `try - except` pierde utilidad. Si quieres saber si la tabla existe o no, puedes hacerlo mediante una query a la base de datos.

Además de estos errores, dos observaciones:

- Te recomiendo seguir las [recomendaciones de PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) en cuanto al nombre de las variables.
- Si estás usando wildcard para importar tkinter (`from tkinter import *`), debes saber que es una mala práctica en general, usa en su lugar:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk

  mi_entry = tk.Entry(...)
  ```

  o bien:

  ```
  from tkinter import Entry, Button

  mi_entry = Entry(...)
  ```

Con todo ello, un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu código podría quedar así:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk



def  conexion_nombre_de_caso():
    conexion = sqlite3.connect("DB_Casos.db")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    table_name = mi_caso.get()

    qr = '''SELECT count(name)
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE TYPE='table'
              AND name=?'''
    cursor.execute(qr, (table_name, ))
    if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 1 :
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("¡Atención!", f"El caso '{table_name}' ya ha sido creado")
    else:
        qr = f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}
                     (ID VARCHAR(30), NUMERO INT, DESACTIVACION VARCHAR(30))'''
        cursor.execute(qr)
        conexion.commit()
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Base_Datos", f"Caso '{table_name}' creado con éxito")
    conexion.close()


ventana_central = tk.Tk()
ventana_central.geometry("950x200")
mi_caso = tk.StringVar()
introducir_nombre = tk.Entry(ventana_central, textvariable=mi_caso, width=30)
introducir_nombre.place(x=350, y=40)
boton_aceptar = tk.Button(width=8, height=1, text="Aceptar", bg="cornflowerblue",
                          command=conexion_nombre_de_caso)
boton_aceptar.place(x=420, y=65)
ventana_central.mainloop()
```

> **IMPORTANTE:** por desgracia la sentencia para crear la tabla no se puede parametrizar, por lo que el usuario podría inyectar código SQL mediante el `Entry`. Si esto es un problema, lo que puedes hacer para mitigarlo es validar la entrada del `Entry`, mediante regex por ejemplo.